# How can I make this texture of a weevil eye

Tags: modeling, node-editor, shader-nodes

How can I make this texture with nodes, or some other technique. It is an eye of an insect called Weevil. I saw it on the web and was curious how this could be done.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272870/snake-scales-align-to-normal-in-geometry-nodes 
and this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmDv81dMQ6c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might save you geometry to do this with a shader. This one depends on the hexagonal grid group described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161799/35559):

[image]

By using it in a shader-tree like this, in UV Space:

[image]

- You can organically warp the hexagonal grid by shifting the UVs in the map
- Alter the overall scale in U and V
- Change the profile of the cells with the *Float Curve*
- Texture-paint smoothness, per-cell, into the HexMask image, around the edges of the eye, or elsewhere, for effect.

.. for some variation of this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's like spot on, Thanks, for the node set up!